# What is the file extension of a file called "foo.tar.bz2"?

Tags: file-extension

Considering the file named:

```
foo.tar.bz2
```

What is the file extension? Is it `.tar.bz2` or `.bz2`? Is it well defined?

Edit: The question here is one of the definition of a "file extension", or where the separation is between the file's name and its extension: is it "foo|.tar.bz2" or "foo.tar|.bz2"

Answer (score 0):

The standard file extension would be `.tar.bz2`, but `.tbz2` should suffice as a shortened extension.

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite the question I'm asking. I have a file with that name, I'm asking where is the separation between file name and file extension? Is it foo|.tar.bz2" or just "foo.tar|.bz2"?

Comment: The extension would technically be `foo.tar|.bz2`, but tar can auto-pickup on some archive types so in practice it's usually `foo|.tar.bz2`

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. I'm going to be opening it programmatically, though, rather than using tar.

Comment: You'd want to open it as a bz2 file first then, and then open that with a tar library.

Comment: The file I used was just an example. The underlying problem is I have a file in a proprietary binary format, which may or may not be compressed using bzip2 (foo.bar|foo.bar.bz2). I'd like to be able to open it generically, but, by this definition, I can't trivially use file extension to do so...

Comment: Try using the `file` command on an example file. It should give you something. And as for the second part, if it has the extension bz2, it's probably bzip2 compressed

Answer (score 0):

> tar - is archive file
>   bz2  - is compressed with bzip

to unarchive and get all files you should type in command line unix:

```
tar jxf foo.tar.bz2
```

after that you will have files unarchived and extracted

extension is the last one **.bz2**